# How to access relay environment outside fragment container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relay, relaymodern

I have a component wrapped in createFragmentContainer(), which I think is how this component got 'relay' attached to it as a prop. Then somewhere in this component we have:

`commitMutationAsync(this.props.relay.environment, {something, something});`

Now I want to call commitMutationAsync somewhere else, is there a way to get this relay environment instance without wrapping HOC onto a component?

I don't know the change between relay modern and relay.
Is Relay.Store a potential solution?

Answer (score 0):

`import environment from 'src/environment'` (or whatever the environment's path is)

and don't forget to export it from the file